# How to use Houndify to record User response?

Tags: houndify

Here's the flow of conversation that I am trying to achieve using Houndify and it's Custom Commands feature:

User: "Add task"

Houndify: "What is name of your task?"

User: `<Says Task name>`

Houndify: "What is end date of task?"

User: "This Saturday"

The `Task Name` from the user can be any word in English. I need to be able to capture what the user says and trigger the response of ClientMatch #2.

I have used Custom Commands and here's what I have done:

In ClientMatch #1, I have the expression ("add" | "insert").[("a")] .("task"). I also have the response "What is name of your task?".

**What I currently have:**
In ClientMatch #2, I have the expression [("*")] as a wildcard. I have the response "What is end date of task?"

**What I must have:**
In ClientMatch #2, I need to have an expression that captures User's `<Task name>` instead of [("*")]. And then trigger the same response as above.

I am able to reach ClientMatch #1 easily as it matches the patter of query. But once ClientMatch #1 is triggered, Houndify does not seem go to ClientMatch #2. Or so I think.

What is the expression that is equivalent to a wildcard that can trigger ClientMatch #2? Or how do I capture User's response where the User simply states the task name?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please refer houndify

CONVERSATION-STATE

https://www.houndify.com/docs#conversation-state